# pass agruments/parameters to included launch file in yaml

Tags: ros, ros2, roslaunch, yaml

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How would you pass arguments / parameters to an included launch file? The following doesn't work and gives the following error: `Unexpected key(s) found in 'include': {'param'}`

```
launch:

- include:
    file: "$(find-pkg-share test)/launch/test.launch.py"
    param:
    -
      name: "color"
      value: "red"
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/406375/pass-agruments/parameters-to-included-launch-file-in-yaml/) by [waspinator](https://answers.ros.org/users/4020/waspinator/) on ROS Answers with karma: 122 on 2022-09-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

use "arg" instead of "param" to pass arguments into an included launch file. Names and values must all be strings in quotes.

```
launch:

- include:
    file: "$(find-pkg-share test)/launch/test.launch.py"
    arg:
    -
      name: "color"
      value: "red"
```

---

Originally posted by [waspinator](https://answers.ros.org/users/4020/waspinator/) with karma: 122 on 2022-09-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0